# Code to find quadratic roots fail when huge numbers are used

Tags: java, quadratic

I got this problem from an online course and here I had to write a small program to find quadratic roots, and the return type should be `Set<Integer>`. I am still learning Java and still not familiar working with those types.

I think everything is not wrong until this part,

```
if(discriminant > 0) {
        root1 = (int)(-b + Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
        root2 = (int)(-b - Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
        result.add(root1);
        result.add(root2);
    }
```

As I have to return the final roots as a `Set<Integer>` type I had to force convert double to int returned by 'Math.sqrt'. I am not sure if this is what causing the issues. And if so I am not sure if how to solve this, because I can't add double values to a `set<Integer>`.

I tested this code with few test cases, and it failed when using really big values, like ~2,000,000,000 for c.

And this is the code I came up with so far.

```
public class Quadratic {


public static Set<Integer> roots(int a, int b, int c) {
    int root1;
    int root2;
    int discriminant = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<Integer>(); 
    
    if(discriminant < 0) {
      String rootsAreImaginary = "Roots are imaginary";
      System.out.println(rootsAreImaginary);
    }
    if(discriminant == 0) {
        root1 = (-b) / (2 * a);
        root2 = root1;
        result.add(root1);
        result.add(root2);
    }
    if(discriminant > 0) {
        root1 = (int)(-b + Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
        root2 = (int)(-b - Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a);
        result.add(root1);
        result.add(root2);
    }
    return result;
}
```

If there are better ways to do this, please feel free to show me. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: @AKSingh Thank you for your comment. So then is there a way to use double as the data type to do the calculation and still output a ```Set<Integer>``` value?

Comment: In Java, the max precision for `int` is `2x10^9`. Anything beyond that will cause *overflow problems*. Even if you pass `a=b=c=10^6`, your program will fail since `a*c` results in `10^12` which an `int` cannot hold

Comment: We don't know the details of the exercise, but it is probably only asking for integer roots?

Comment: @Henry Thank you for the comment. I was given it like this,
`public static Set<Integer> roots(int a, int b, int c) {
//to do
}`

Comment: @Sujee0_0 Nope there is not. If you use `int` it will result in *overflow errors* for big numbers.  You can use `Long` instead of `Integer`. Your program seems logically correct.

Comment: You might consider using `BigDecimal` or `BigInteger` as appropriate.

Comment: @WJS thank you for the comment! Can I add BigInteger to my `Set<Integer> result`? Pardon me if I sound stupid.

Comment: Not as an Integer.  It would have to be a set of that type.  e.g. `Set<BigDecimal>`

Comment: @WJS okay I see, thank you! May be there are some issues with the question. But I will rewrite the code with those suggestions.

Comment: @Sujee0_0 If you haven't done so already, check out the Wiki entry on the quadratic equation.  It provides alternate formulae and references to avoid certain round off and overflow errors.

Comment: @WJS That's a great idea, thank you! it didn't come to my mind, I will check that out.

Comment: One more observation.  you have the following `root1 = (-b) / (2 * a);`.  b and 2 and a are all integers.  So you will drop any fractions in the division.  Even if you assign to a double it is too late.  E.g. 1000/33 == 30 even if you assign it to a double.  Those values should all be doubles or should be cast to a double.  `(double)1000/33 ==  1000. /30 == 30.30303`

Comment: And be careful when comparing floating point values.   `System.out.println(0. == .000000000000001);` prints false.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234479/discussion-between-sujee0-0-and-wjs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `BigDecimal` or `BigInteger` to do the computations. These would have to be stored in a Set of the proper type, e.g. `Set<BigDecimal>`.

Both of those classes have methods to return the value of the related primitive (`BigDecimal#doubleValue() and BigInteger#longValue()`).  But precision and size concerns still apply as you may not be able to fit the result into the class's related primitive.